# Authorize users at a machines level?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, http

Is is possible to authorize users at a machine level. For example, only when using authorized computers (my personal laptop or other managers' pcs) can one get access to the admin page? Any other computers should either get a denial of access message or something else. Authorized computer may still provide their own admin username and password in case people could fake a machine's identity, maybe. I'm not a security expert though.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I misunderstand, but you are asking to only allow visitors on specific machines to access your website?

Jumping right into a solution here. The first question is how do you know which machines are "manager's" machines? Do you have a list of their IP addresses? Do you have some other ID on them?

If you have their IP addresses, then IP Whitelist them, and block all other ip addresses.

If you do not have their IP address, then you are limited. There is no machine ID that can be accessed through a web browser, so you'll need to create your own ID by setting a long lived cookie and a registration process.

Since you already have a login process, this next part is fairly easy. You've used this solution before. When you sign in to google mail and click "remember me" and don't need to sign in the next time your computer restarts, google has basically marked (set a cookie) your machine as yours.

Now, if you want to get super fancy, enterprises have NAC setup. Every system is identified before being allowed to connect to the network. Certain systems are given more access than others. For example, at a software development company, engineers may be given access to a production network while sales staff is not. When they connect, sales staff are move to a restricted vlan after identifying who they are and who the machine belongs to. If that were the case for your company, then you would whitelist an entire subnet block.

Last point. Chase bank uses the machine cookie concept like so: The first time you login they ask your username and password. Then the send a code to your phone or some third-party channel. After you enter the code, the set a machine cookie (same old cookie). The next time you login, they ask for username and password, then look for the machine cookie. If the machine cookie is there, then they don't make you enter the code again.

You could make that your registration process, except you provide the manager with a code they can enter. I don't think you want to get much more complex than a static password to register the machine, but if you did, you can generate one time tokens following the spec in [rfc 4226](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4226).

Answer (score 0):

You can't restrict access to specific computing device (as there are many types of devices used and there's no universal thing to bind to) but depending on your application design you still can solve your problem. You need to bind not to computer, but to other hardware device which is not possible to duplicate.

One of such devices is a hardware cryptotoken or cryptocard with the certificate and a private key in it. The user plugs the device to USB or to card reader respectively, then he authenticates on the server using the certificate and private key stored on this device). Client-side authentication using certificates is a large but well-known topic so I don't discuss it here.

While it's possible to move the cryptographic device to another computer system, it's not possible to duplicate it or extract the private key from it. So you can (with certain high level of reliability) assume that there exists only one copy of the private key and it's stored on certain particular device.

Of course you would need to create another certificate for each device, but this is not a problem - the only purpose of these certificates is to be accepted by the server, so the server can issue new certificates when needed.